# Sencha Touch 2 Filter a List Store

Tags: javascript, filter, sencha-touch, extjs, store

I have the following code as my main javascript file for displaying a list + buttons. It all shows properly and everything like adding items to the store works great, but is there a simple way to get the list to only display values where the name equals a certain value?

```
Ext.define("MyProject.view.Main", {
extend: 'Ext.NavigationView',
requires: ['Ext.NavigationView', 'Ext.dataview.List'],
xtype: 'myproject-main',

config: {
items: [
{
  title: 'List of Data',
  layout: 'fit',
  xtype: 'container',
  itemId: 'listContainer',
  items: [
  {
    xtype: 'list',
    store: 'DataStuff',
    itemTpl: '{name}',
    emptyText: 'No data added yet'
  },
  {
    xtype: 'container',
    docked: 'bottom',
    padding: '5px',
    layout: 'hbox',
    items: [{ xtype: 'button', itemId: 'addBtn', text: 'Add Data', ui: 'confirm', width: '50%', align: 'left' }, { xtype: 'button', itemId: 'updateBtn', text: 'Update Data', ui: 'action', width: '50%', align: 'right' }]
  }
  ]
}
]
}
});
```

I had thought there was a simple filters: category I could add under the store but couldn't find anything that worked.

Answer (score 0):

List displays items that provided by store. For controls list filter you should control his store fitlers.
Example

```
var store = list.getStore();
store.filter('category', 'first');
//or
var customFilter = function(record){
     return soAnyCheckForRecods(record);
}
store.filterBy(customFilter);
```

More information about filters look here http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store